# Given a matrix, how do I determine whether the entries of the matrix are Independent and Identically Distributed (IID)?

Tags: matlab, matrix

The matrix was not generated with a `rand` function; rather, it was obtained by collecting data from a server. I want to know if there is a method to check if any given matrix, A, has IID entries or not.

Comment: What you want is like trying to estimate a function's derivative knowing only the value of the function at one point. You simply can't. Independence and distribution are concepts that refer to random variables, not to numbers. You'd need a large set of matrix realizations to estimate the distribution and to test independence.

Answer (score 1):

statistically, that's impossible. unless you have some other assumptions which you didn't mention - you'll need that information in advance.

take a look on the following link for more information
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/how-can-the-iid-assumption-be-checked-in-a-given-dataset